# iOS ready made template?

Tags: ios, mobile

I am a web developer / programmer that is in my infancy on mobile development on iOS. I would like to start a new project on an mobile app, but usually if i were to develop a web site, I would download some html template on the web with ready made of html and css or CMS like wordpress if my application is complicated or huge, so that i do not need to design the pages from scratch. I would just need to add some php or J2EE programming towards the pages to develop my application.

So now my question is, what about iOS? Is there any ready made iOS templates with good design? I tried searching for templates on the web but doesn't seems to find any. Am I starting at the wrong foot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you even try what is provided in Xcode?

Comment: Yes i have. I do understand that your point is that XCode already have a good platform and good ui design such as the storyboarding and UIbutton or UItextfield. But i just want to know is there more options available in the market? Is there more ready made app that have been design and I can just put my logics / programming into it. aka open sources...

Answer (score 1):

I've seen companies that offer such things, but they cost money and I don't think they are worth it. Using storyboards to build an interface and then putting in your logic code is pretty straightforward. If you need some tutorial type help getting started, [raywenderlich.com](http://raywenderlich.com) is a great site.